# checking if elements of source string is part of target

Tags: php, arrays

I have two strings:

```
$source = "AA|BB|CC|DD";
$target = "AA|CC|DD|EE|BB";
```

The delimiter in both is `|`

I have to find out if the elements of the source are present in target or not . (In any order)

The program should return `true` if the elements of source are present in target, `` otherwise.

To do that I am storing the `$source` and `$target` in their own array and using `array_intersect`

```
$source_arr = explode("|",$source);
$target_arr = explode("|",$target);

$exists = (count($source_arr) == count(array_intersect($source_arr, $target_arr)));
if ($exists == 1) {
  echo "True";
else {
  echo "False";
}
```

The program always return `false`.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: You have an extra " on line 1

Comment: Works fine for me: [**Codepad**](http://codepad.org/3XZ7OcPQ)

Comment: @Rottingham sorry corrected it

Comment: Code works fine: http://ideone.com/TPFdcr (Assuming we remove the extra " on both lines.)

Comment: @Jessica OMG! why not for me..

Comment: Probably because that isn't your real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
  $count = 0;
  foreach($sourcearray as $item){
     if(in_array($item, $targetarray))
        $count++;
  }
  if (count($sourcearray) == $count)
     echo "true";
  echo "false";
```

Comment: This will return `true` on the first item it finds that exists in both; the OP wants "all" to exist. Perhaps if you invert your logic a bit it could work.

Comment: The OP's code actually does work, so I would suggest not spending too much more time on it. (You still have multiple errors.)